# Declared permisisons CAMERA in package by default

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

When i install my application first time and try to use my CAMERA it doesn't ask for permission

**MY PERMISSION METHOD**

```
public boolean hasPermissionInManifest(Context context, String permissionName) {
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    try {
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        final String[] declaredPermisisons = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if (declaredPermisisons != null && declaredPermisisons.length > 0) {
            for (String p : declaredPermisisons) {
                if (p.equals(permissionName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
    return false;
}
```

When i debugg my app i found that the `CAMERA` permission is presente in the `declaredPermisisons`

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
 ...
```

NOTE : the permissions found in `declaredPermisisons`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about why your code is not working but this is what I use for permission:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!checkPermissionFromDevice())
            requestPermission();
    }
    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        },REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice() {
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        return camera ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer i will try it later

Comment: It worked buddy thank you please reorgniz your code and why not upvote the question

Comment: Only the padding is not organized, anything else that needs to be organized?